# How to connect to remote MySQL server via SSH using JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL server via SSH in my Java project.
How can I integrate SSH connection with JPA?

I'm using Netbeans 6.9.1, JPA, MySQL 5.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to tunnel to a remote mysql which only listens to localhost (or is firewalled)

The easiest way is then

1. [setup a trust relationship](http://nosheep.net/story/password-less-ssh-login/) between the account running the application server providig the JPA service to your application
2. create the tunnel using `ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 mysql.server.org` to create a tunnel which will connect port 3306 on the appservers host to port 3306 on the mysql server's localhost port.
3. Configure JPA to connect to `localhost:3306`

Answer (score 4):

You can't ... You have to set up  external ssh tunel.

```
ssh -N -f -L 3307:localhost:3306 login@remotwhostwithmysql
```

Later change connection-url
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/yourdatabase