# Connecting to postgresql using SSH and Java

Tags: java, postgresql, ssh

I am trying to connect to postgresql in java using JSch but I am getting an exception, which I can't figure out what the problem is. I have used the approach provided in this tutorial https://www.journaldev.com/235/java-mysql-ssh-jsch-jdbc

Code and exception are as follows

```
public class MySqlConnOverSSH {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    int lport = 5656;
    String rhost = "192.168.1.1";
    int rport = 5432;
    String user = "abc";
    String password = "abc";
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:" + lport + "/dbtwitter";
    String driverName = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    Connection conn = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(user, rhost, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected");
        int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
        System.out.println("localhost:" + assinged_port + " -> " + rhost + ":" + rport);
        System.out.println("Port Forwarded");

        //mysql database connectivity
        Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Database connection established");
        System.out.println("DONE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("Closing Database Connection");
            conn.close();
        }
        if (session != null && session.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Closing SSH Connection");
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am getting the following exception

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection.<init>(Jdbc3gConnection.java:24)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:382)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:260)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at evidenceofvaccine.MySqlConnOverSSH.main(MySqlConnOverSSH.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:257)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:253)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:94)
... 9 more
```

Comment: That article is almost 7 years old - How about a ssh tunnel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778067/how-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-server-via-ssh-using-jpa

Comment: JSch is creating SSH tunnel

Comment: Yeah, but it is not working, so why not go for a far easier method?

Comment: I just tried this code and it works for me. I generated the same error you see when I changed the port. Is your Postgresql instance listening on 5432 (it is the default port)?

Comment: Yes the port is okay as I can fetch data from postgresql using SSH in DataGrip with port 5432

Comment: The code is working for me as well!

Answer (score -1):

This might not solve specifically the issue, but I faced something similar with the SSH tunnel while migrating some Java apps.

The SSH gave me several issues and I discovered it was easier to create the connection, not in the code itself, but creating a bridge using the console/terminal with something like this:

```
ssh -L localhost:MY_LOCAL_PORT:MY_LOCAL_URL:MY_DB_PORT -N -J MY_LOCAL_USER -i ~/MY_LOCATION/MY_FILE_NAME.pem VM_USER
```

Later, I used my app `localhost:9991` as my new connection, and then it worked as expected. I avoided modifying my Java apps with over-complicated code and somehow could be reused in my opinion.